# GIT Credential Helper what to remove?

Tags: git

I used to use AWS CodeCommit and needed to take advantage of GIT credential helpers. Now, I want to remove this but I don't know what to remove. Here is the configuration for credential helpers:

```
$ git config credential.helper
!aws codecommit credential-helper $@
```

What is the default configuration for credential.helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a load of different ones you can use, although different versions of git come with different helpers by default.

A few examples are:

```
git config --global credential.helper store # keeps credentials in a text file
git config --global credential.helper wincred # on git for Windows - keeps credentials in Windows credential manager
git config --global credential.helper manager # also git for Windows - Microsoft's own helper
```